# VBScript cannot delete folder

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I have a VBScript program that creates a folder in the user's temp folder:

```
set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
temp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
dropzone = temp & "\{d450c76c-2ad8-4f73-af8a-ccc5ba28036a}\"

If Not fso.FolderExists(dropzone) Then 
    set NewFolder = fso.CreateFolder(dropzone)
End If
set NewFolder = Nothing
```

At the end of the program, I would like to delete that folder. I tried this but it gives me a permission denied error:

```
set deletefolder = fso.GetFolder(dropzone)
deletefolder.Delete(True) 
set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@giodamelio Weirdly enough, I put the line `msgBox dropzone` before your code and it worked. When I comment out the `msgbox` it wont work?

- Your code or pc is too fast! :D
- You probably don't dispose/close files you use or store in that folder (or not closed correctly)

Answer (score 5):

- No, not a problem with timing
- No, not a problem with dispose
- No, not a problem solved by MsgBox
- No, not a problem with attributes
- No, not a problem with current directory path
- No, can't use Kill
- No, it's not access denied
- No, you don't have to shell out
- No, MSDN documentation won't tell you

YOU JUST HAVE TO DELETE THE TRAILING BACKSLASH IN THE PATH BECAUSE DELETEFOLDER DOESN'T LIKE IT.

Now, feel free to shoot the messenger ...

Comment: If you use objFolder.Delete(True), the trailing backslash shouldn't be a problem. If you use objFSO.DeleteFolder, the extra trailing backslash causes Error: "Path not found", Code: 800A004C.

Answer (score 2):

Check the attributes of the file and set to 0 if it's not already set.

```
set deletefolder = fso.GetFolder(dropzone)
if deletefolder.Attributes=0 then
 deletefolder.Delete(True)
else
 deletefolder.Attributes=0
 deletefolder.Delete(True)
end if
set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, I put the line `msgBox dropzone` before you code and it worked. When i comment out the msgbox it wont work???

Comment: @giodamelio - sounds like you got it working.  I was about to suggest setting fso to nothing after creating the file and opening another instance of it before doing the delete.  Sometimes fso seems to not want to release a file handle.

Comment: a verb "deletefolder" isn't a great variable name. It's confusing to read for someone seeing the code for the first time. Why not oFolder? (`o` prefix indicating object type). Or, oFolderToDelete.

Answer (score 1):

It's very, very probably not an actual "access denied". More likely it's an "can't delete while files are open". Close any open references to that folder (text streams, processes you might have started, look carefully) and do

```
fso.DeleteFolder(dropzone)
```

See [MSDN documentation on `DeleteFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca0at0xh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I ran a process with `shell.run()` but I set `set shell = Nothing` afterwards.

Comment: @giodamelio: Yes, but setting `shell` to nothing does not stop the process. You have to wait until it's finished. There is a `bWaitOnReturn` parameter exactly for that purpose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to use **Kill(**"folder path"**)**

Comment: can you delete folder through cmd?

Comment: @giodamelio Weirdly enough, I put the line msgBox dropzone before you code and it worked. When i comment out the msgbox it wont work???
- your code or pc is too fast! :D
- you probably dont dispose/close files you use or store in that folder (or not closed corectly)

Comment: Thanks that is just right, if you add it to an answer ill mark it at correct.

Answer (score 0):

for DeleteFolder to work, the current directory for the script should not be a part of the path of the folder to be deleted.
Use Shell.CurrentDirectory to change the current directory to some system path and then call DeleteFolder.
I have verified that this works.
Check [this.](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/browse_thread/thread/6fd7fd5c672acc01?pli=1)

Answer (score -1):

If your folder path has a backslash, the method will throw an error! Most of my scripts have a backslash at the end of paths purposely using another function, so I removed the last character of my path (backslash) and viola!